# debug step into a stored procedure on SQL server 2008 R2 on Microsoft sql management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have to debug a stored procedure on SQL server 2008 R2 on Microsoft sql studio.

In my SQL query, I have to call two store procedures :

```
EXEC @return_value = [my_database].[dbo].[store_procedure1]
```

in `[my_database].[dbo].[store_procedure1]`, I need to call another procedure:

```
execute @return_status = store_procedure2
```

in debugging mode of SQL server management studio, I can step into `[store_procedure1]` but, I cannot step into `[store_procedure2]`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SSMS debugging is pretty much useless, use print statements to check where your control in during execution.

Comment: @M.Ali, I cannot print out anything when I debugged into store_procedure1. thanks